# Question about repurposing WordPress 404 handler

Tags: php, 404-error

I've been experimenting with repurposing WordPress's 404 handler/template file for a Real Estate site that I'm developing. I understand that when a non-existent URL is requested, the 404 page gets served up and that it returns a 404 status code (instead of a 200).  But I've recently found a way to adapt the 404 template file so that it does something a bit more creative.  More specifically, I'm first parsing the non-existent URL that was requested, and then using the returned value to query an external API and then display the returned data. So far it's working much better than I'd expected, though I'm aware of one significant issue that I'm hoping I can address.

**In those situations where the 404 handler is served up, yet data is returned from querying the external API, .. how can I then -- and only then -- re-write the "404" header information so that it's a "200" status code?**  I ask because I don't want these "Page Not Found" entries littering our Google Analytics reports and mucking up the site's SEO ranking.

Here is an example non-existent URL which triggers the serving up of the 404 handler:

https://example.com/property/123-four-street/

I am parsing this URL using the following PHP code snippet:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path_parts = explode('/', $url);   
$address = $path_parts[2];  
$parsedaddress = str_replace("-", " ", $address);                   
echo $parsedaddress;
```

The "parsedaddress" value is then used to query the external API, and what I'd then like to have happen logic-wise is something along the lines of ...

**if (query returns valid MLS data)**

**then  (force a "200" status code and display the MLS data)**

**else (retain the "404" status code and display the 404 error page)**

I've already added this custom function to my functions.php file, which is successfully changing the default page title for the 404 handler ... so I know that I can hook in to it.  But how might I adapt this so that it conditionally rewrites the header information?

```
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title_parts ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {               
        
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path_parts = explode('/', $url);   
        $address = $path_parts[2];  
        $parsedaddress = str_replace("-", " ", $address);           
        
        $title_parts['title'] = ucwords($parsedaddress) . ' | AAA Real Estate;
    }

    return $title_parts;
} 
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-- Yvan

Comment: I like this question... like what you’re doing... here’s my immediate thought... the 404 status code is registered before that page loads and before your code runs, because that’s how it knows to run your code.  So I’m wondering if it’s even possible to retroactively change the status code?

Comment: You bring up a good point.  As I've been researching this, however, I kept coming across references to this WordPress status_header()" method:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/status_header/

It's just not clear as to exactly how or where I'd need to implement this within the WordPress framework's execution chain,  or if the search engine crawlers would even acknowledge it .. as you've just pointed out.

Does anyone else here have any information or advice regarding this?

Thanks,
-- Yvan

Comment: As a potential fallback plan .. is there any way to set up special filters within a Google Analytics account (or within an .htaccess file, perhaps) that would purposefully ignore 404s for any URLs that include "/properties/" in them?  By that I mean ... find a way to tell Google "Yes, we already know about those URLs, but please don't hurt our SEO ranking because of them."

Comment: Can anyone here provide any additional feedback?  I certainly don't want to continue down this path if it's a dead end. Please advise -- thanks.

Comment: How do I request attention to this question that I posted?  Do I answer my own question or something?

Comment: If you have any further details you could update your question, or set a bounty on it, or delete it and add a new question with updated info...

Comment: I’m curious to see the answer to this, if you like I can put a bounty on it.

Comment: Yes -- please put a bounty on it - and thank you.
 Pardon my noob-ness here, but what exactly is a "bounty"?

Comment: Oh, a bounty is when you offer up a share of your reputation points to make getting an answer to your question more appetizing.  It kinda promotes your question and makes it more prominent.  So when you accept an answer someone get's the extra reputation points you assigned to the question.

Comment: I'm really curious to see if someone can figure this out.  This seems like a useful thing to have bookmarked and in my 'locker'.  :-)  Anyway, bounty set.

Comment: I think this is a pretty significant abuse of WordPress's core mechanisms, and may conflict with behaviors from plugins that depend on them. A better solution would be to set up a rewrite rule to handle all of the behaviors associated with the `/property/` path.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion regarding this, and feel like it's a worthy topic of discussion in and of itself.  To clarify, however, the /property/ path that you're referring to (which correlates to a custom post type) is currently being used to serve up actual posts (that return and display data from the WP DB). The approach that I'm experimenting with is -- "If a genuine post exists and is associated with this URL .. then retrieve and display it. Otherwise, serve up the expected 404 page template, parse the URL, and do something creative with it. Just please - server - don't tell Google!" :)

Comment: Yvan, the bounty is about to expire, let me know if KAGG's answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the tested code, you can use it as a mu-plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Filters whether to short-circuit default header status handling.
 *
 * Returning a non-false value from the filter will short-circuit the handling
 * and return early.
 *
 * @param bool     $preempt  Whether to short-circuit default header status handling. Default false.
 * @param WP_Query $wp_query WordPress Query object.
 *
 * @return bool
 * @since 4.5.0
 */
function pre_handle_404_filter( bool $preempt, WP_Query $wp_query ) {
    global $parsed_address, $api_results;

    $parsed_address = get_parsed_address();

    if ( ! $parsed_address ) {
        return $preempt;
    }

    // Make a request to  API, get status.
    $status      = true; // For debug purposes.
    $api_results = null;

    if ( $status ) {
        // Save results to $api_results.
        // Return true to avoid 404 processing by WP.
        return true;
    }

    return $preempt;
}

add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', 'pre_handle_404_filter', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Handle 404.
 */
function handle_404() {
    global $parsed_address, $api_results, $wp_query;

    if ( ! $parsed_address ) {
        return;
    }

    // Set 404 here to prevent bugs in get_header().
    $wp_query->set_404();

    get_header();
    echo 'API Results'; // Output $api_results here.
    get_footer();
    exit();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'handle_404', - PHP_INT_MAX );

/**
 * Get parsed address from the request URI.
 * Make sure we have an address in the URI, otherwise return an empty string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_parsed_address() {
    $request_uri =
        isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ?
            filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) :
            '';

    if ( url_to_postid( $request_uri ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $path_parts = explode( '/', $request_uri );
    $part1      = isset( $path_parts[1] ) ? $path_parts[1] : '';

    if ( 'property' !== $part1 ) {
        return '';
    }

    $address = isset( $path_parts[2] ) ? $path_parts[2] : '';

    return str_replace( '-', ' ', $address );
}

/**
 * Filter page title.
 *
 * @param array $title_parts Title parts.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title_parts ) {
    global $parsed_address, $api_results, $wp_query;

    if ( ! $parsed_address ) {
        return $title_parts;
    }

    $title_parts['title'] = ucwords( $parsed_address ) . ' | AAA Real Estate';

    return $title_parts;
}

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

We catch 404 via `pre_handle_404`, make the API request and save results. Please note that it works when we have parsed address in the URI only.

Later, on `template_redirect` event, we check again that have parsed address and set back 404 status to prevent bugs in the get_header(). Please note that we intercept `template_redirect` as early as possible, at `- PHP_INT_MAX` priority to execute our code before standard `template_redirect` hook in the WP core.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I understand that I'll need to tinker with this a bit and that I can't just straight up copy and paste -- but know that when I did try to copy and paste these into my child theme's functions.php file as-is, I consistently got critical errors. The "pre_handle_404_filter" and "get_parsed_address" methods seem to play well together, -- but I think I'm going to need to do a bit more work on the "handle_404" method.  Question -- can I safely implement this in my child theme's functions.php file?

Comment: I do not know your API, and cannot write the related code. Code is 100% working, you can just copy and paste it as a mu-plugin. Create a folder mu-plugins under wp-content, create there a file with any name like `my-404.php`, copy and paste code there, including the first line `<?php`. And that's it. - you have created a must-use plugin.

Comment: If you get a critical error, you do something definitely wrong, Code is tested on my test site and works as expected. Just report at least here what kind of error do you have.

Comment: You're correct that it works as an mu-plugin (that's why I was asking if it would work in functions.php).  But I'm still having a problem. This is designed to treat ALL urls that have "property" and an address in them as 404s, when that isn't the case. I have properties set up as custom posts that have the exact same url structure, and I need to display them. So the custom 404 handling be can't be triggered based on the URL structure. I think I might need to update the get_parsed_address() method so that it first checks to see if the post actually exists before doing the custom 404 handling.

Comment: I do not know your task in details, and I have solved the main problem - careful processing of 404 with accessing your API. You can extend the code, and add some array with the acceptable property names to check the `$address` - it is easy, Return empty string if the address is not in the array of allowed ones.

Comment: Yes - you did solve my main problem - and thank you for that. Now I just need to figure out how to check to see if a post ID actually exists for the requested URL (which I am admittedly struggling with at the moment).  But I guess I can take if from here. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To check if url belongs to the existing post, I have added 3 lines with `url_to_postid()` into  `get_parsed_address()`. It is tested and works properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119293/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-yvan-gagnon).

Comment: Are you unsatisfied with the answer? Our chat did not show that. Why put bounty, and do not mark the question as solved, thus depriving me a bounty?

Comment: Yes .. I am satisfied with the answer.  I just don't know how to mark a question as solved.  Also, I'm not the person who put the bounty on this, so I'm not sure if maybe that person is responsible for marking the question as solved? Just tell me what I need to do .. if anything.

Comment: On the left-top side of my answer is the upvote/downvote counter and a grey checkmark under it. Looks like that: https://prnt.sc/ynyqm1. Click on the grey checkmark to make it green, it means that you have accepted the answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for your help -- and for your patience.

Comment: Thanks. You are welcome.